# Go through the divs and add a part to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I go through on elements which contains same class and take a part of the div?

```
<div class="Selected">This Is selected
   <div class="apptId">4320573</div>
   <div class="details"><span class="timestamp">Due at 09:00</span></div>
</div>
<div class="Selected">This Is selected
   <div class="apptId">4320573</div>
   <div class="details"><span class="timestamp">Due at 09:00</span></div>
</div>
<div class="Selected">This Is selected
   <div class="apptId">9852183</div>
   <div class="details"><span class="timestamp">Due at 12:00</span></div>
</div>
```

I have 3 divs with class "Selected". I count it with the next code:

```
    var po_list_number = document.querySelectorAll('.Selected').length;
    alert(po_list_number);
```

My question is, how can I see if there is duplicated div? (The apptId content if same)
If there is, count just once and take the time once as well.

So I need to create a second list which containts just time but never duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the contents of the DIVs in a `Set` and get the size of the set. Since sets can't have duplicate values, this is the number of unique strings.

```js
const apptid_divs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.Selected .apptId')];
const apptid_set = new Set(apptid_divs.map(div => div.textContent.trim()))
console.log(apptid_set.size);
```

```html
<div class="Selected">This Is selected
   <div class="apptId">4320573</div>
   <div class="details"><span class="timestamp">Due at 09:00</span></div>
</div>
<div class="Selected">This Is selected
   <div class="apptId">4320573</div>
   <div class="details"><span class="timestamp">Due at 09:00</span></div>
</div>
<div class="Selected">This Is selected
   <div class="apptId">9852183</div>
   <div class="details"><span class="timestamp">Due at 12:00</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't retrieve the time and create a unique list as requested by the original question.

Here's the correct JavaScript code that outputs a `uniquePoListCount` count and a key:value `uniquePoList` object of unique apptId details as requested.

Update: I included extracting the "This Is selected" text as requested from this answer's comment. It's not in a unique selectable element, so it relies on the specific HTML structure from the original question and it's extracted with termination after a new line.

```js
// Select all .Selected  elements
let poList = document.querySelectorAll('.Selected')

// List the element objects in the original poList array
poList = Object.entries(poList)

// Define variables to avoid declarations in a loop
let poListEntry = ''
let poListEntryId = ''
let poListEntryText = ''
let poListEntryTextIndex = 0
let poListEntryTextParsed = false
let uniquePoList = {}
let uniquePoListCount = 0

// Loop through poList entries
for (let poListKey in poList) {
    // Set the poListEntry to a variable
    poListEntry = poList[poListKey][1]

    // Set the apptId to a variable
    poListEntryId = poListEntry.querySelector('.apptId').innerText

    if (typeof uniquePoList[poListEntryId] === 'undefined') {
        // Populate uniquePoList with [{apptId: {"details": "timestamp"}}] after verifying uniqueness of apptId
        uniquePoList[poListEntryId] = {
            "details": poListEntry.querySelector('.details .timestamp').innerText
        }

        // Set the innerText for parsing "This Is selected"
        poListEntry = poListEntry.innerText

        // Empty the previously-used entry text variables
        poListEntryText = ''
        poListEntryTextIndex = 0
        poListEntryTextParsed = false

        while (poListEntryTextParsed === false) {
             // Extract the "This is selected" text from each unique .Selected element as requested in this answer's comment
             if ((poListEntry[poListEntryTextIndex] === '\n')) {
                 // Exit the loop after reaching a new line
                 poListEntryTextParsed = true
                 continue
             }

             // Append the character to poListEntryText for the current index
             poListEntryText += poListEntry[poListEntryTextIndex++]
        }

        // Populate uniquePoList with [{apptId: {"text": poListEntryText}}] after extracting the "This Is selected" text
        uniquePoList[poListEntryId].text = poListEntryText

        // Increment count of unique apptIds
        uniquePoListCount++
    }
}

console.log("Count of unique appointments")
console.log(uniquePoListCount)
console.log("List of unique appointments")
console.log(uniquePoList)
```

```html
<div class="Selected">This Is selected 1
    <div class="apptId">4320573</div>
    <div class="details"><span class="timestamp">Due at 09:00</span></div>
</div>
<div class="Selected">This Is selected 2
    <div class="apptId">4320573</div>
    <div class="details"><span class="timestamp">Due at 09:00</span></div>
</div>
<div class="Selected">This Is selected 3
    <div class="apptId">9852183</div>
    <div class="details"><span class="timestamp">Due at 12:00</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Liam, I tried to modify a little because I need the "This Is selected" text from the divs with "selected" class. Just the same like with the timestamp, I need the unique values. I keep getting undefined errors

Comment: I updated my answer with the "This Is selected" text included.

Comment: I put the all HTML body to jsfiddle and the js code what you sent and its works fine. But when I try to use it in the site I keep getting the next error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'querySelector')
    at HTMLButtonElement.saveDatas (This all is in a saveDatas function, when I click the button this need to run). Because those datas what we need to select to uniquePoList are loaded after site load with ajax I belive. And this is why I put everything in button (saveDatas function) because I know when its ready to be saved to the uniquePoList

Comment: This is because the `saveDatas` function loads before the `document.querySelectorAll('.Selected')` elements are available. What does the `saveDatas` function code look like? It'd help to see the entire JavaScript code. Since the `saveDatas` function uses the `.Selected` elements, it needs to wait until the `.Selected` element nodes are loaded before adding the `click` event listener to the button.